# Who is Scoutmaster Kevin?

Tags: character, reference, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool-2

During this scene in *Deadpool 2*, after Wade wipes his face, he asks, 'Scoutmaster Kevin?'.

Is he referring to a real-life person? A character in another movie perhaps? Or does this scene mean something else? I could not understand the joke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found few explanations for the scene. Couldn't find any official statement so I'm putting both for you.

One is it's a reference to Josh Brolin's 1980s cult classic movie Goonies. Deadpool have few lines from the same movie which made Brolin famous.

> Well, as Scoutmaster Kevin used to say... "There's a first time for
>   everything,son." Give me your best shot, One-Eyed Willy.

One-Eyed Willie was the infamous captain of the pirate ship featured in Goonies. It was Willie’s map Mikey found in his parent's attic, dragging Brand on an adventure he didn’t ask for. An article on [thegamer](https://www.thegamer.com/deadpool-2-easter-eggs-true-fans-caught/) had some references to the movie Basic Instict which Wade tries to do the same move like Sharon Stone (Catherine Tramell) did.

Another theory I found was that Deadpool hints about under-age abuse, with later revealing Firefist and more children were abused at the care-home they live. This scene is believed a hint to all the under-age abuse. As stated in [theactionpixel](https://www.theactionpixel.com/2018/05/comics/tapreviews-deadpool-2/),

> the context and the uttering of two words alluded to sexual abuse of a
>   minor. Talk of Fire Fist being abused also came up, which at first
>   felt like it alluded to the sexual variety. Flashback scenes however
>   just insinuated your everyday ol’ Abu Ghraib-esque Mutant torture
>   sessions.

I'm not sure this''d be a good answer, but these are the things I can find for now.
You can read the linked articles and find out some more.

Comment: I believe its a combi of both...sexual abuse and goonies reference...being it deadpool and the fact the film is made for an older audience it seems like they assumed the viewership would get the sexual humour and the reference...atleast, thats how I understood the scene.

Comment: Note that Deadpool could be joking about underage abuse without needing to have been subjected to it, or (even if subjected to it) without actually recognizing the alleged scoutmaster Kevin.

Comment: It's probably the latter. There's a similar joke in the first movie when he first interacts with Colossus on the bridge about being able to recognise a specific person by their genitals.

Comment: One-Eyed Willy - The famous pirate from Goonies. The common joke is to call someone One-Eyed Willy if they only have one eye. 

Scoutmaster joke - It is widely known that Boy Scout leaders have been found guilty in many cases of sexual abuse of the boys there are supposed to be leading and mentoring. The joke here being that Deadpool experienced this kind of abuse.

Comment: Whether it predates *The Goonies* or not, "one-eyed willie" has an alternate meaning meaning of male genitals. This joke is obviously a reference to sexual abuse and a *Goonies* reference at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

It's a sexual predation reference.

It's difficult to not get explicit, but, wiping his face and then saying that is suggestive of it bringing to mind him having ejaculate on his face, and it evoking memories of his scoutmaster.

"One-eyed Willy" would be a euphemism for a penis - which is often referred to as someone's "Willy," and the "one-eyed" reference is also one that is often used in penis euphemisms because of the single opening at the end.  It is not a reference to a pirate in a movie.

> One eyed cave salamander
>   One-eyed bath tub eel
>   One-eyed blue-vein
>   One-eyed cave dweller
>   One-eyed Charlie and the Stink Twins
>   One-eyed cornhusker
>   One-eyed cow killer
>   One-eyed custard chucker
>   One-eyed Fred
>   One-eyed giant
>   One-eyed gopher
>   One-eyed hip snake
>   One-eyed horny newt
>   One-eyed Jack
>   One-eyed lizard with the saggy chin
>   One-eyed milkman
>   One-eyed moisture missle
>   One-eyed monster
>   One-eyed nightcrawler
>   One-eyed snake
>   One-eyed superhero
>   One-eyed throbbing python of love
>   One-eyed trouser mouse
>   One-eyed trouser psychic
>   One-eyed trouser python
>   One-eyed trouser snake
>   One-eyed trouser trout
>   One-eyed wiggling welshman
>   ***One-eyed Willy***
>   One-eyed wonder weasel
>   One-eyed wonder worm
>   One-eyed wrinkle-necked trouser trout

[Dicktionary: The largest list of penis euphemisms](https://gregology.net/reference/dicktionary/)

"There's a first time for everything" - referenced in another answer would be someone getting someone else to do something for the first time that they otherwise wouldn't.

Look at the image on that video capture - his head/face are at crotch level to the person in front of him.

Put it in the context of just about every other line in the movie - it's non-stop sexual innuendo and double-entendre.

It is, 100%, without a doubt, a joke about someone young being abused by being forced by an adult authority figure to give them oral sexual service.